# JQuery plugin for loading data (from a database) on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I am wondering if there are any JQuery plugins for loading data(from a database) on scrolling to the bottom of a webpage, much like the way Facebook and Twitter work. I tried looking throughout Google but found nothing useful. Any links or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's called "Infinite Scrolling"

Comment: @dabious: http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/

Comment: Thanks @gopi1410, I will take a look through those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for infinite scroll. Here are few Jquery Plugins which might help you.

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll

Hope this what you are looking for..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
// do something
}
});
```

Comment: well, small code for your work!